# Extracting Multi Values to Points and Dissolve afterwards with ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, dissolve

I want to extract Multi Values from 2 Rasters to Points and dissolve these points afterwards with an ArcGIS ModelBuilder model. In the Dissolve function I want to make some statistics of the extracted Values (Min. and Max.)

[image]

My Problen: In the statistic fields of Dissolve tool I can’t select the new generated fields of the "Extract Multi Values to Points"-Tool . The new generated fields can also not be selected for dissolving. 
Questions:
1) Why are the new generated fields not offered in the dissolve tool?
2) How can I make my model run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually add the field to your dissolve tool input. There is a button called "Add Field" just below the dissolve field selection. You can also input any field name you want into statistics field(s), even if it doesn't appear in the list.